# All the commits done by me in all the branches

Tags: git

I know I can use

```
git log --author='Johnny'
```

to see all the commits done by Johnny. However this will get me result only for the current branch. Is there a way to get all the commits done by Johnny in all the branches in last 2 days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
git log --branches --since=2.days --author=Johnny
```